# Issue Detecting Checkbox with Adobe DTM

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to track when a check-box is clicked. I have an event based rule set as so:

- Event Type - click
- Element or Tag Selector - input#ctlSignon_chkRememberMe
- Bubbling - Allow events on child elements to bubble

I'm doing some testing and I'm not even seeing DTM detect clicks on the check-box (Debug turned on)? Below is the code on the actual page for this element.

`<div class="icheckbox_minimal hover" style="position: relative;">
<input id="ctlSignon_chkRememberMe" type="checkbox" name="ctlSignon$chkRememberMe" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</ins></div>`

I have no idea why this is happening or what to do next? Unfortunately this code is not public facing yet so I can't provide a URL. FYI.. the checkbox is part of a form

`<form name="MainForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="MainForm" autocomplete="off" onreset="if (window.setTimeout) window.setTimeout('DES_OnReset(false);', 100);">`

Thanks!

Comment: I made a page with a generic form and checkbox on it and have dtm in debug mode and I see messages e.g. `SATELLITE: detected focus on INPUT`,`SATELLITE: detected click on INPUT`,`SATELLITE: detected focus on INPUT`, so at face value, DTM detects it just fine.  So, there must be something else on your site conflicting or suppressing it.  If I had to take a guess, I'd say maybe something else is overlayed on top of it.  But it's a random guess.. can't confirm without being able to see the site

Comment: You should be seeing a `SATELLITE: detected ..` message for *something*  when you click on it, even if it just gives generic top level `SATELLITE: detected click on HTML`.   What is it showing in console when you click on it?  If it is showing absolutely nothing then you must have something else triggering first that is completely suppressing/preventing anything else hooked to it from happening

Comment: +1 Crayon Violent. Yes - if there is any function attached to the form click events that returns false this will cancel the DTM listener.